# Django take too much time to send a request

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Django takes too much time to load a page. After debugging with the debug tool, I find that it take too much time to send request, is there any advice to enhance the performance? The view includes a Paginator.

After checking the performance with debug-tool:

```
request: 11855
response: 1
domloading: 1122
dominteractive:12080
```

Comment: Terminology points: Django doesn't load pages, your browser loads pages. Django doesn't send requests, it sends responses. Your browser sends requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need check your sql code in Django model or view. It seems that you spend too much time to load information from the server. Consider using **select_related** method as follows:

> Screen.objects.filter(Q(name_*icontains=query)
>                                                      | Q(editor*_username__icontains=query))\
>                   .select_related("build__id","name")

Comment: Cphilo, Thank you! there is huge enhance after your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you started django project in developer model.
Maybe you can use uwsig+nginx.
uwsgi ： http://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html
nginx + uwsgi ： http://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: Thank you, orangleliu! I will set up uwsig next step